# Best approach to Android navigation back button on Nested Navigator

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, router, navigator

I have a Scaffold that holds a `Navigator` object. Each route has a possibility of holding an `appBar`.

### MainScaffold

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBarSelector(),
      ...
      body: WillPopScope(...},
          child: Navigator(
            key: _navigatorKey,
            initialRoute: '/',
            onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
              Widget builder;
              switch (settings.name) {
                case '/':
                  ref.read(routeNameProvider.state).state = '/';
                  builder =  HomeScreenBody(
                    automotive: content["stuff"],
                    vehicleTypes: content["more_stuff"]["types"],
                  );
                  break;
                case '/users':
                  ref.read(routeNameProvider.state).state = '/users';
                  builder = UsersScreenBody(
                    stuff: content["stuff"],
                    moreStuff: content["more_stuff"],
                  );
                  break;
                default:
                  throw Exception('Invalid route: ${settings.name}');
              }
              return PageRouteBuilder( ...
                pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _animation, __animation) => builder,
            ...
      bottomNavigationBar: CustomBottomNavigationBar(navigatorKey: _navigatorKey),
    );
```

### AppBarSelector

```
class AppBarSelector extends AppBarIcon {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return selectAppBar(ref);
  }

  Widget selectAppBar(WidgetRef ref) {
    String routeName = ref.watch(routeNameProvider);
    switch (routeName) {
      case '/garage':
        return AppBarIcon(
          titleText: "Garage",
          icon: Icons.add,
          route: VehicleRegistrationScreen(),
        );
        break;
      case '/home/list':
        return AppBarIcon(
          titleText: ref.read(appBarTitleProvider),
          icon: Icons.add,
          route: SomeList(),
        );
        break;
      default:
        return SizedBox(height: 0);
    }
  }
```

## Problem

Whenever I route to a page, the appBar shows/dissapears just fine. But once I press the `Android Navigation BackButton` there is no `routing` happening, thus the `appBar` does not change how it should be and remain after popping the `route` on a screen that should not have an `appBar`.

#### Question

How do I make `AppBarSelector()` respond to my `Android Navigation BackButton`?

#### Approach made

I have tried the `persistent_bottom_nav_bar 4.0.2` package but that lakcs things like a `persistent appBar` or the possibility to have a transparant `BottomNavigationBar`.

I wonder how other people have dealt with this situation.